# Jenkins disable tag every build in dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have job dsl as below

```
pipelineJob('demo/Development') {
     definition {
    cpsScm {
        scm {
                 git('https://github.com/demo/demo.git','development')
        }
        scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
    }
}
}
```

When the job is created it has addtional behavior added by default for create a tag for every build. How can I disable this on the job dsl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the problem

```
 git('https://github.com/demo/demo.git','development',{node -> node / 'extensions' << '' })
```

just needed to add the configure block to get rid of the extensions block, if required it can be used to modify xml directly.

Answer (score -1):

Another option (as at Jenkins Job DSL 1.64) is to add an empty configure block.  This is useful if you need to set additional values for the scm, e.g.:

```
pipelineJob('DSL_Pipeline') {

  def repo = 'https://github.com/path/to/your/repo.git'

  triggers {
    scm('H/5 * * * *')
  }
  description("Pipeline for $repo")

  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote { url(repo) }
          branches('master', '**/feature*')
          scriptPath('misc/Jenkinsfile.v2')
          extensions { }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ is a useful tool to hack on the DSL and find out what works.